# Writing Unit-Test for a Class

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have a class with constructor having 6 arguments. I want to write a Test fixture for this class. I tried calling these arguments in the test constructor, but failed to create test fixture

```
   class TestHandler
   {
   public:
       using Buffer            = common::dt::ByteBuffer;
       using HardwareInterface = 
            common::interfaces::SyncBufferProducerConsumer<Buffer>;

       explicit TestHandler(slave::cache::FullKeyValueCache& 
                       cache, const CommandHandler& commandHandler,
                       const RTDCache& rtdCache, HardwareInterface& 
       hardwareInterface, bool& statusChanged, bool& alarmsChanged)
              : m_keyValueCache(cache)
              , m_commandHandler(commandHandler)
              , m_rtdCache(rtdCache)
              , m_hardwareInterface(hardwareInterface)
              , m_statusChanged(statusChanged)
              , m_alarmsChanged(alarmsChanged)
          {
          }

          template <typename T>
          void respond()
          {
               m_checksumHelper.checksumEnabled() = 
                            m_commandHandler.checksumEnabled();
               auto responseMessage               = 
                    SalviaSerial::traitsTemplate::Response();

               fillResponse<T>(responseMessage);
               common::dt::GuardedWriteBuffer<uint8_t> 
                               writeBuffer(m_hardwareInterface);
               common::extensionCards::library::serialise
                      (responseMessage, writeBuffer.get_range());
               m_checksumHelper.calculateAndSetChecksum
                                  (writeBuffer.get_range());
           }

   private:
           template <typename T>
          void fillResponse(SalviaSerial::traitsTemplate::Response& 
                              response);
          slave::cache::FullKeyValueCache&    m_keyValueCache;
          const CommandHandler&               m_commandHandler;
          const RTDCache&                     m_rtdCache;
          HardwareInterface&                  m_hardwareInterface;
          DOBusImplementation::ChecksumHelper m_checksumHelper;
          bool&                               m_statusChanged;
          bool&                               m_alarmsChanged;
   };
```

I need to write a Test fixture for TestHandler class, later use this t4xt fixture to test different responses available. I need suggestions on calling this class in TestHandlerTest.cpp and a method to start unit test.

Comment: Are you using any unit test framework? If so, you should mention it and if available use the tag for that framework

Comment: @Klaus I want to use google testing framework

Comment: FYI, if your question has been answered, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a [test fixture](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md#test-fixtures-using-the-same-data-configuration-for-multiple-tests-same-data-multiple-tests) in Google Test, you’ll need to (a) inherit from the `testing::Test` class and (b) ensure your fixture class is default-constructible  (can be constructed without any arguments).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, will go through the doc and come back again

Comment: The document that you have mentioned provided really good information. I am now writing the mock class for different arguments and will return back for further doubts